# Gradient and Hessian of a function defined in terms of matrix inverse

Tags: derivatives, convex-optimization, hessian-matrix

Let $\mathbf{I}_m$ be the $m$-dimensional identity matrix and $\mathbf{0}_m$ be the $m$-dimensional zero matrix. The matrix $D(\mathbb{x})$, where $\mathbb{x} = (x_1, \dots, x_n)^T$, is defined as:
$$
D(\mathbb{x}) = \begin{pmatrix}
    x_1 \mathbf{I}_{m} & \mathbf{0}_m & \mathbf{0}_m & \dots & \mathbf{0}_m \\
    \mathbf{0}_m & x_2 \mathbf{I}_{m} & \mathbf{0}_m & \dots & \mathbf{0}_m \\
    \mathbf{0}_m & \mathbf{0}_m & x_3 \mathbf{I}_{m} & \dots & \mathbf{0}_m \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \dots & \vdots \\
    \mathbf{0}_m & \mathbf{0}_m & \mathbf{0}_m & \dots & x_n \mathbf{I}_{m}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
That is, $D(\mathbf{x})$ is a diagonal matrix with entries from $\mathbf{x}$ on the diagonal (each entry is replicated $m$ times).

Now, given a vector $\mathbf{v}$ and a positive-definite matrix $\mathbf{P}$, we define a function on the domain $\mathbf{x} \geq 0$:
$$
f(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{v}^T (\mathbf{P} + D(\mathbf{x}))^{-1} \mathbf{v}
$$
Is there a way to express the gradient and Hessian of $f$?

Comment: Have you had a chance to take a look at the [Matrix Cookbook](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/publication_details.php?id=3274)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's define $$Q(x)=P + D(x) = P + \mathop{\textrm{diag}}(x) \otimes I_m$$ where $\mathop{\textrm{diag}}$ maps the vector $x$ to the corresponding diagonal matrix, and $\otimes$ denotes the Kronecker product. This makes it a bit simpler to see that
$$\frac{\partial Q(x)}{\partial x_i} = \frac{\partial D(x)}{\partial x_i} 
= e_ie_i^T \otimes I_m = (e_i \otimes I_m) (e_i^T \otimes I_m)$$
where $e_i$ is unit vector with a $1$ in the $i$th element. Expressed without the Kronecker product, $e_ie_i^T\otimes I_m$ is the block matrix with $I_m$ in the $(i,i)$ block position and $0_m$ everywhere else; and $e_i \otimes I_m$ is the $i$th block column of that matrix.

Armed with this information, we proceed per the aforementioned Matrix Cookbook. From equation 40, we have
$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial Q(x)^{-1}}{\partial x_i} &= - 
Q(x)^{-1} (e_ie_i^T \otimes I_m) Q(x)^{-1} \\
&= - Q(x)^{-1} (e_i \otimes I_m) (e_i^T \otimes I_m) Q(x)^{-1}
\end{aligned}$$
We can obtain a very convenient interpretation of this quantity if we
apply a corresponding block structure to $Q(x)^{-1}$. Let's call this quantity $R$, so that
$$R \triangleq Q(x)^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} 
R_{11} & R_{12} & \dots & R_{1n} \\ R_{21} & R_{22} & \dots & R_{2n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ R_{n1} & R_{n2} & \dots & R_{nn} 
\end{bmatrix}$$
With this structure in place, we see that right-multiplying $Q(x)^{-1}$ by $e_i \otimes I_m$ obtains the $i$th block column. Let's denote that column by $R_{i:}$.

This leads us to this first derivative:
$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x_i} &= - 
v^TQ(x)^{-1} (e_ie_i^T \otimes I_m) Q(x)^{-1}v \\
&= - v^TQ(x)^{-1} (e_i \otimes I_m) (e_i^T \otimes I_m) Q(x)^{-1}v \\
&= - v^T R_{i:} R_{i:}^T v = \|R_{i:}^T v\|_2^2\end{aligned}$$
The second partial derivatives are
$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial^2 f(x)}{\partial x_i x_j} &= 
2 v^TQ(x)^{-1} (e_ie_i^T \otimes I_m)Q(x)^{-1} (e_je_j^T \otimes I_m) Q(x)^{-1}v \\
&= 2 v^TQ(x)^{-1} (e_i \times I_m)(e_i^T \otimes I_m)Q(x)^{-1} (e_j\otimes I_m)(e_j^T \otimes I_m) Q(x)^{-1}v \\
&= 2 v^T R_{i:} R_{ij} R_{j:}^T v
\end{aligned}$$where $R_{ij}$ is the $(i,j)$ block of $Q(x)^{-1}$.

Comment: New edit with what I think is a significantly simpler result.

Answer (score 0):

$
\def\bbR#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\t{\otimes}
\def\B{B^{-1}}
\def\Eii{E_{ii}} \def\Eij{E_{ij}} \def\Ejj{E_{jj}}
\def\Cij{\widehat C_{ij}} \def\Cjj{\widehat C_{jj}}
\def\Fij{\widehat F_{ij}} \def\Fjj{\widehat F_{jj}}
\def\Fii{\widehat F_{ii}}
\def\Si{\sum_{i=1}^n}
\def\Sj{\sum_{j=1}^n}
\def\Sk{\sum_{k=1}^n}
\def\Sij{\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n}
\def\bbR#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\diag#1{\op{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\op{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
$Let $\{e_k\}$ denote the standard basis vectors for $\bbR{n}$ and define the matrix $\Eij=e_ie_j^T$ whose $(i,j)^{th}$ component equals ${\tt1}$ and all other components are zero, and the following matrix variables
$$\eqalign{
I_m &\in\,\bbR{m\times m} &\{{\rm identity\;matrix}\} \\
X &= \Diag{x} &\in\bbR{n\times n} \\
D &= X\t I_m &\in\bbR{mn\times mn} \\
B &= P+D &\in\bbR{mn\times mn} \\
C &= \B V\B \;&\in\bbR{mn\times mn} \\
F &= C\B+\B C \;&\in\bbR{mn\times mn} \\
V &= vv^T &\in\bbR{mn\times mn} \\
\Cij &\in\,\bbR{m\times m} &\{{\rm submatrix\;of\;}C\} \\
\Fij &\in\,\bbR{m\times m} &\{{\rm submatrix\;of\;}F\} \\
}$$
It will also be convenient to use the Frobenius product $(:)$, which has the following properties
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \Sij A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \frob{A}^2 \qquad \{ {\rm Frobenius\;norm} \}\\
A:B &= B:A \;=\; B^T:A^T \\
C:\LR{AB} &= \LR{CB^T}:A \;=\; \LR{A^TC}:B \\
\LR{A\t B}&:\LR{Z\t Y} = \LR{A:Z}\LR{B:Y} \\
}$$
Use the above notation to write the objective function and calculate its gradient
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= V:\B \\
d\phi &= V:d\B \\
  &= V:\LR{-\B dB \B} \\
  &= -\LR{\B V\B}:dB \\
  &= -C:\LR{dX\t I_m} \\
  &= -\LR{\Sij\Eij\t\Cij}:\LR{dX\t I_m} \\
  &= -\LR{\Sij\LR{I_m:\Cij}\Eij:dX} \\
  &= -\LR{\Sij\trace{\Cij}\Eij}:\Diag{dx} \\
  &= -\diag{\Sij\trace{\Cij}\Eij}:dx \\
  &= -{\Sij\trace{\Cij}\diag{\Eij}}:dx \\
  &= -{\Sij\trace{\Cij}\:\delta_{ij}e_j}:dx \\
  &= -{\Sj\trace{\Cjj}\:e_j}:dx \\
\grad{\phi}{x} &= -{\Sj\trace{\Cjj}\:e_j} \;\doteq\; g \\
}$$

---

Before tackling the Hessian, we need to calculate the following
$$\eqalign{
C &= \B V\B \\
dC &= -\B\LR{dX\t I_m}C - C\LR{dX\t I_m}\B \\
\trace{dC} &= -\LR{C\B+\B C}:\LR{dX\t I_m} \\
  &= -F:\LR{dX\t I_m} \\
  &= -{\Sj\trace{\Fjj}\:e_j}:dx \\
}$$
But another way to calculate this quantity is
$$\eqalign{
\trace{dC} &= \trace{\Sij\Eij\t d\Cij} \\
 &= \Sij \trace{\Eij}\t \trace{d\Cij} \qquad\qquad \\
 &= \Sij \delta_{ij} \trace{d\Cij} \\
 &= \Sj \trace{d\Cjj} \\
}$$

---

Now we're ready to calculate Hessian (aka the gradient of $g$)
$$\eqalign{
dg &= -\LR{\Sj\trace{d\Cjj}\:e_j} \\
  &= +\LR{\Sj\trace{\Fjj}\:e_je_j^T}dx \\
\grad{g}{x} &= \Sj\trace{\Fjj}\:e_je_j^T \;\doteq\; H \\
}$$
So, for either derivative, all you need to do is calculate the $(C,F)$ matrices, partition them into $(m\times m)$ blocks, then calculate the traces of the diagonal blocks multiplied by the corresponding basis vectors.